# Interpreting coefficient of log transformed independent variable in negative binomial regression

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

My problem is...

...how to interpret coefficients associated with log-transformed independent variables. I know that now I have log units, which depend on the choice of basis for the logarithm. For natural log as in your example, an e
e-fold change in Independent_var_1 is associated with the indicated change in the dependent variable.

for example: y= a + aln(X) + e, where y is count data.

Therefore, a e-fold change in X associates with a change in y.

Q1: Is this interpretation correct? Q2: is the change in y in units or percentages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not sure if negative binomial regression restricts your intercept and slope to be both $a$. I am assuming that is not the case.

Given two scenarios, where $x$ differs by $k$ time:

$$\ln(E(y)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \ln{x}$$

and

$$\ln(E(y')) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \ln{kx}$$

Subtract the first one from the second:

$$\ln(E(y')) - \ln(E(y)) = \beta_1 (\ln{kx} - \ln{x})$$

$$\ln \frac{E(y')}{E(y)} = \beta_1 (\ln{\frac{kx}{x}})$$

$$\frac{E(y')}{E(y)} = \exp^{\beta_1 (\ln{k})}$$

So, if $x$ changes by $k$ times, average of $y$ changes by $\exp^{\beta_1(\ln{k})}$ times.

Suppose $x$ increases by 20% and $\beta_1$ is 0.79, then $y$ changes by $\exp^{0.79(\ln{1.2})} = 1.155$ times, a 15.5% increase. Predicted change in $y$ is expressed in percentage or factor, not in its own unit.